# Ошибка "Для пакета «python3-pip» не найден кандидат на установку" в ubuntu на виртуальной машине

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

Есть виртуальная машина, на ней ubuntu,я без проблем установил python3, а вот python3-pip не получается, пишу sudo apt-get install и python3-pip sudo apt install python3-pip, все равно пишет Для пакета «python3-pip» не найден кандидат на установку

Comment: https://losst.ru/oshibka-package-has-no-installation-candidate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Ubuntu пакет именуется как "python-pip", а не "python3-pip". Поэтому корректная команда будет выглядеть так:

```
sudo apt install python-pip
```

или:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

Во избежание таких казусов перед установкой можно сделать поиск по имени пакета в репозиториях.

```
apt search [название-пакета]
```